# ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID from jQuery Using Reverse Proxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

I am having an issue with 'ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID' when making a request from a website.

First of all, am really a bit of a novice when it comes to setting up and using certs... so this is probably something stupid that I have ether done or not done!

I have a ssl certificate `www.my-dummy-url.abc` and `api.my-dummy-url.abc` (obviously `my-dummy-url` is for example only). Where `api.my-dummy-url.abc` is the certificate `Subject Alternative Name` and `www.my-dummy-url.abc` is the certificate `Subject`.

The Apache Web sever, is hosted at `www.my-dummy-url.abc`, whilst a reverse proxy points '`api.my-dummy-url.abc` to a Raspberry Pi running a little node.js API endpoint (/weather).

I have set node.js up to use express: `https.createServer(ssl_options, ...`, where `ssl_options` is my cert.pem and key.pem. CORS is enabled (`app.use(cors());`) and `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'` is present in the response.

The Website (apart from the API call) renders fine at https://www.my-dummy-url.abc (Chrome).
The API, (https://api.my-dummy-url.abc/weather) if requested within the address bar of a Chrome browser or through Postman receives the correct JSON response.

However, from my website as a jQuery `$.get` function I get the following error:

```
GET https://api.my-dummy-url.abc/weather net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

Any ideas, helpers, pointer or solutions will be gratefully received...

---

As an addition, if I use Edge rather then Chrome, it works...!

Kind Regards,
Harold Clements

Comment: Can I check your Subject is something like `CN=www.my-dummy-url.abc, O=something, C=GB` i.e. without the `https://` and formulated as a DN, and your SAN should be `api.my-dummy-url.abc` also without the `https://` and flagged as a DNS name?

Comment: It's also possible the error is coming from the reverse proxy, because it doesn't trust the certificate on the raspberry pi, but I'm not sure how to tell that from the error.

Comment: Thank you @Rup

I should have been a bit more clear. The 'Subject' is  `www.my-dummy-url.abc` and there are two Subject Alternative Names: `my-dummy-url.abc` and `api.my-dummy-url.abc`.

Comment: OK... I think it was a caching issue with Chrome. This was despite clearing the cache many times within the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was that Chrome was caching the certificate somehow. After shutting down and coming back to it the next day, it was working fine.